# How to install canon LBP2900 without communication error?

Tags: printing, canon, mint

I have tried to install canon LBP 2900 in linux, and How to install canon LBP2900, using the steps in link http://answerexpress.blogspot.com/2018/09/install-canon-lbp2900-driver-in-linux.html. shows communication error when i run the command `captstatusui -P LBP2900` in terminal

Comment: Mint is off-topic here, as is non-Ubuntu software. Sorry. That's why Mint and Canon have their own support forums. Looks like the most likely reason is that the `ccpd` daemon is not running, or you started it with the wrong parameters. Since it's not our software, that's a guess.

Comment: okay, i'm sorry

Comment: but that solutions not working for me

Comment: According to [openprinting database](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-LBP_2900) the printer support status is **"Paperweight"**. So sell it and buy HP or modern Canon. I tried to make it working on 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS without success.

Comment: Try to follow this instruction - https://riku.titanix.net/wordpress/canon-2900-working-on-linux/ .

Comment: okay, i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system which i was tried, didn't have lp0 port, i was tried to assign my printer to lp0 port, the system have lp1 port. when i replaced command with `sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp1`

instead of `sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0` there by i fixed the issue

https://answerexpress.blogspot.com/2018/09/install-canon-lbp2900-driver-in-linux.html?showComment=1537011224549#c8502123259659790456

Comment: well done! You nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use driver auto-installation script: [canon_lbp_setup.sh](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0Byemcyi98JRjejF1TlVYek05eUU) for LBP series printers.